# react native flatlist render an extra row at the bottom

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Flatlist rendered 4 rows but the data variable only have 3 objects

Array items:

```
const data = [
      { type: 250, amount: 2, points: 150 },
      { type: 250, amount: 2, points: 150 },
      { type: 250, amount: 2, points: 150 },
    ];
```

My flatlist:

```
   <FlatList
    style={styles.list}
    data={data}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    contentContainerStyle={{
      paddingTop: pxToPercentage(8),
    }}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.rowStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.typeStyle}>{item?.type}</Text>

          <Text>{item?.amount}</Text>

          <Text style={styles.pointStyle}>{item?.points}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }}
      />
```

Edit:
There is no error here, but a blank view between flatlist and footer how can i remove it
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no Error, I ran also the same code in my project, and this is working fine.

```
import React from "react";
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const data = [
    { type: 250, amount: 2, points: 150 },
    { type: 250, amount: 2, points: 150 },
    { type: 250, amount: 2, points: 150 },
  ];
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: "grey", margin: "10px" }}>
              <Text>
                {item?.type} | {item?.amount} | {item?.points}
              </Text>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can see in the picture, this is the output of the above code, there are only three lists, as I change the background color to grey.

[image]

Comment: yeah you are right there is no error but why i get that blank space

Comment: I guess this blank space is due to style having margin or padding, which you might use in rowStyles <View style={styles.rowStyle}>. Show me all the styles you used.